# during docker build, add-apt-repository returns "keyserver receive failed: No name"

Tags: docker, proxy, dns, gnupg, apt

I am trying to build a Docker image for building Zoo-Project, following [installation guidelines](http://www.zoo-project.org/docs/install/debian.html).

I am behind a company proxy, so I set up environnement to point to it :

```
root@myContainer$ env
HTTP_PROXY=http://10.xxx.y.zzz:3128
https_proxy=http://10.xxx.y.zzz:3128
http_proxy=http://10.xxx.y.zzz:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.xxx.y.zzz:3128
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the following command from the Dockerfile or from within the container, it keeps failing :

```
root@myContainer$ add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
 Official stable UbuntuGIS packages.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpl5mo2xz1/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

I tried the following with no success :

- apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 226213AA  : *keyserver receive failed: No name*
- apt-key adv --keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 226213AA : *keyserver receive failed: No name*
- the same with url replaced by ip address (91.189.90.55, 18.191.65.131) : *keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available*

My resolv.conf looks like this (from within the container):

```
root@myContainer$  more /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
nameserver 10.171.108.2
search rennes.mycompany.fr
```

Anyone has a tip here?

Comment: Have you tried launching your container with `--net=host` option?

Comment: @mulg0r now I have. The consequence is that it asks me for dirmngr, but after it has been installed, I keep having the same error.